# javascript regular expression to allow 0 to 999.99

Tags: regex

I am using the following javascript expression for validating input which should allow 0 to 999.99. It is allowing more than two digits as well.  As per requirement it should allow only two digits after decimal.

```
^([0-9]{0,3})|([0-9]{0,3}\.([0-9]{1,2}))$
```

please suggest me correct expression to allow values 0 to 999.99.  only two digits after the decimal.

Comment: For instance, give us one wrong number that it's matching...

Comment: It works for me...999.99 is matched, but 999.999 is not.

Comment: The regex you posted also allows for an empty string. You might want to make the first group allow for 1..3 instead of 0..3 as a result of that fact unless an empty string is valid.

Answer (score 0):

If your digits don't have preceding zeros like 01 02 03 then this regex can help:

```
^([1-9]\d?\d?|0)(\.\d{1,2})?$
```

**[Live demo](http://regex101.com/r/kB7oJ2)**

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the multiple IDE you're using may corrupt "\",

so I hope the following code may work for you,

at least it worked for me.

`^[0-9]{1,3}(\\\\\\.[0-9]{1,2})?$`

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you need ?

```
  /^([0-9]{0,3})(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/
```